# How do I call my generate random numbers which has size 100 to simulation of playing dice 100 times

Tags: matlab, static

I want to simulation of playing dice 100 times by generate a sample with size = 100 of a random variable Compute the point estimator P for the probability of the event ’even.

This is my function ,I comment "i-loop" because I want to write in another function and while I calling myRand()

```
function [result]=myRand()

%generate a sample with size = 100

 X = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
 P = [1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6];


size=100;
%n=100;  % playing dice 100 times
result=zeros(100,1);
  %for i=1:n
    for j=1:size 

         result(j,:)=randsample(X,1,true,P);
    end
  %end
end
```

My problem is that when I call myRand()

```
function simulate()

    % simulate trowing dice

    countEven = 0; % count even
    n=100;  % playing dice 100 times
    throw_dice = zeros(n,2);
    for i = 1:n

        throw_dice(i) = myRand();

    end
end
```

Definitely I have an error "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same." 
 Any idea how can I call my function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**myRand:**

First in `myRand` it is bad practice to use `size` as variable name as it is already a function in Matlab.

Secondly, you can generate all 100 variables in one go with

```
randsample(X,100,true,P)
```

Thirdly, you should take the number of variables in as an argument `myRand(number)`

In total:

```
function [result]=myRand(number)

%generate a sample with size = number

X = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
P = [1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6 1/6];

result=randsample(X,number,true,P);
```

`myRand` will now return `number` repititions of rolling a die.

**Simulate:**

Regarding your `simulate` function then you repeat `myRand` a hundred times. In your version `myRand` generate a hundred random variables. In other words you ask for the hundred variables a hundred times.

So you have to make a choice, should `myRand` generate 100 variables, or should you call it 100 times (where it only make 1 at a time). Typically it is faster to generate all at once.

Thus your `simulate` is now:

```
function simulate()

% simulate trowing dice
n=100;  % playing dice 100 times
throw_dice = myRand(n); %Ask for n rolls

%*************
%Insert code to count even rolls.
%*************
```

Alternatively it is:

```
function simulate()
% simulate trowing dice
n=100;  % playing dice 100 times
even_rolls = 0;
for i = 1:n %Roll the die n times
    throw_dice = myRand(1); %Ask for 1 number
    %*************
    %Insert code to count even rolls.
    %*************
end
```

Comment: `myRand` here is the same as the inbuilt function `randi([1 6], 1, number)`.